# Call to AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer results in CrashIfClientProvidedBogusAudioBufferList only on MacOS Sierra

Tags: objective-c, core-audio

I have an audio program that makes a call to AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer with the following code:

```
OSStatus error = AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer(recorderObj->audioConverter,
                                                     MyAudioConverterCallback,
                                                     (__bridge void *)playerLocal,
                                                     &ioOutputDataPackets,
                                                     convertedData,
                                                     &streamDesc);
```

When this code runs on 10.6-10.11, it works fine. When the code runs on 10.12, it crashes with the following message

```
Crashed Thread:        16  com.apple.audio.IOThread.client

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]
```

The call stack ends in CrashIfClientProvidedBogusAudioBufferList.

Most articles, documentation and mailing lists would say that I have a bad output buffer but for the life of me, I cannot tell what I would be doing wrong but still have my code work on all versions of MacOS but the latest. Here is how I am setting up the buffer:

```
AudioBufferList *convertedData = (AudioBufferList*)malloc(sizeof(AudioBufferList) * 2);

convertedData->mNumberBuffers = 1;
convertedData->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels =  2;
convertedData->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = 64 * 1024;
convertedData->mBuffers[0].mData = (UInt8 *)malloc(sizeof(UInt8) * 64 * 1024);
```

Here is the full stack at the point of the crash

```
Thread 16 Crashed:: com.apple.audio.IOThread.client
0   com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox    0x00007fff89b9a330 CADebuggerStop() + 4
1   com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox    0x00007fff89a21e71 CrashIfClientProvidedBogusAudioBufferList + 97
2   com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox    0x00007fff89a2f710 AudioConverterChain::CallInputProc(unsigned int) + 646
3   com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox    0x00007fff89a2f386 AudioConverterChain::FillBufferFromInputProc(unsigned int*, CABufferList*) + 130
4   com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox    0x00007fff89a2f2ee BufferedAudioConverter::GetInputBytes(unsigned int, unsigned int&, CABufferList const*&) + 178
5   com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox    0x00007fff89a2f1b2 CBRConverter::RenderOutput(CABufferList*, unsigned int, unsigned int&, AudioStreamPacketDescription*) + 106
6   com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox    0x00007fff89a2225d BufferedAudioConverter::FillBuffer(unsigned int&, AudioBufferList&, AudioStreamPacketDescription*) + 281
7   com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox    0x00007fff89a2f2c3 BufferedAudioConverter::GetInputBytes(unsigned int, unsigned int&, CABufferList const*&) + 135
8   com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox    0x00007fff89a9369b Resampler2Wrapper::RenderOutput(CABufferList*, unsigned int, unsigned int&) + 183
9   com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox    0x00007fff89a2225d BufferedAudioConverter::FillBuffer(unsigned int&, AudioBufferList&, AudioStreamPacketDescription*) + 281
10  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox    0x00007fff89a2f2c3 BufferedAudioConverter::GetInputBytes(unsigned int, unsigned int&, CABufferList const*&) + 135
11  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox    0x00007fff89a2f1b2 CBRConverter::RenderOutput(CABufferList*, unsigned int, unsigned int&, AudioStreamPacketDescription*) + 106
12  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox    0x00007fff89a2225d BufferedAudioConverter::FillBuffer(unsigned int&, AudioBufferList&, AudioStreamPacketDescription*) + 281
13  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox    0x00007fff89a2253f AudioConverterChain::RenderOutput(CABufferList*, unsigned int, unsigned int&, AudioStreamPacketDescription*) + 99
14  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox    0x00007fff89a2225d BufferedAudioConverter::FillBuffer(unsigned int&, AudioBufferList&, AudioStreamPacketDescription*) + 281
15  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox    0x00007fff89a21d2f AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer + 282
16  com.pc-intercom.Intercom        0x0000000107a52803 0x107a4a000 + 34819
17  com.apple.audio.units.Components    0x000000010a38c97c AUHAL::AUIOProc(unsigned int, AudioTimeStamp const*, AudioBufferList const*, AudioTimeStamp const*, AudioBufferList*, AudioTimeStamp const*, void*) + 2324
18  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio       0x00007fff8a71f951 HALC_ProxyIOContext::IOWorkLoop() + 4369
19  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio       0x00007fff8a71e667 HALC_ProxyIOContext::IOThreadEntry(void*) + 131
20  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio       0x00007fff8a71e38b HALB_IOThread::Entry(void*) + 75
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000108134aab _pthread_body + 180
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001081349f7 _pthread_start + 286
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000108134221 thread_start + 13
```

If anyone has any suggestions on how I can debug this issue, I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: can you link to a small project that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I am working on creating one already.  Once I get it done, I will upload it here.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but I have uploaded a sample project to http://www.desktopintercom.com/downloads/AudioUnitTest.zip.  This simple program will run on 10.11 and crash on 10.12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `MyAudioConverterCallback`, `ioDataPacketCount` is supposed to return frames for LPCM (I guess packets *are* frames for uncompressed audio), so set it to:

```
*ioDataPacketCount = recorderObj->inputBuffer->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize/recorderObj->streamFormat.mBytesPerFrame;
```

Pass a `NULL` `AudioStreamPacketDescription` to `AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer` instead of an array of 1 (this was causing crashes for me on 10.11). Your destination format is LPCM, so packet descriptions are unnecessary because your "packets" are all the same size.

Similarly, your source format is LPCM too, so you can remove the code that returns packet descriptions in `MyAudioConverterCallback` - it's also wrong.

On my machine, I get non-interleaved stereo for `streamFormat` which means `MyAudioConverterCallback` has to fill out `ioData->mBuffers[1]` too.

When setting up your `convertedData` `AudioBufferList`, `sizePerPacket` was using the source format packet size instead of the destination packet size. It should be:

```
sizePerPacket = mOutputFormat.mBytesPerPacket;
```

And finally, even when it's not crashing, this code can't be right because you're recording (say) 512 frames from the microphone, then asking the audio converter to convert 16384 - that's going to give you audio glitches.

Comment: I am working through your changes and I am still getting the crash.  I am not sure that I understand your comment about filing out iodate->mBuffers[0] since it looks like I am filling that out  on lines 27 and 28 inside MyAudioConverterCallback:  

ioData->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
ioData->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = recorderObj->inputBuffer->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize ;

As for your last comment, I have been playing around with those numbers just trying to get this to work.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo - I meant I have two buffers. You should check if you do too.

Comment: When I print ioData->mBuffers I get the following output

(AudioBuffer [1]) $0 = {
  [0] = (mNumberChannels = 1, mDataByteSize = 0, mData = 0x0000000000000000)}

If I am reading this correctly, I am only dealing with one buffer.

Comment: Just our of curiosity, are you able to get the sample program running under 10.12 without crashing?

Comment: You need to look at `ioData->mNumberBuffers` (or `streamFormat->mChannelsPerFrame` & `streamFormat->mFormatFlags & kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved`). I do not have 10.12.

Comment: I did look at ioData->mNumberBuffers and I do see that I have 2 buffers.  In my tests, this sample project runs fine under 10.11 but in 10.12, the same code crashes.  Even with the errors you point out, why would it run on 10.11 and crash on 10.12.  It is a bummer that you do not have 10.12 since it seems that you understand core audio better than I do and you might be able to point me in the right direction to solving this crash. :-(

Comment: Try fixing all the errors first (& filling out _both_ `AudioBuffer`s - the crash _is_ complaining that you supplied a bogus buffer list), then let's see if it still crashes on 10.12. From my point of view it _should_ crash on 10.11 too.

Comment: You are correct on the filling out of both buffers.  Once I filled out the second buffer, the code started working on 10.12 and 10.11.  I am now also wondering why it did not work on 10.11. I have marked your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Awesome! Does that mean I get the bounty?

Comment: I would assume so.  I marked your answer as the answer and my rep has gone down by the bounty amount.  Did yours go up? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. It hasn't gone up yet. I think you can do it manually, but since you accepted the answer it'll probably be automatically rewarded once the bounty expires: http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: I think I have officially awarded it. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

> The callback is given an audio buffer list pointed to by ioData.  This
> buffer list may refer to  existing buffers owned and allocated by the
> audio converter, in which case the callback may   use them and copy
> input audio data into them.  However, the buffer list may also be
> empty     (mDataByteSize == 0 and/or mData == NULL), in which case the
> callback must provide its own     buffers.  The callback manipulates the
> members of ioData to point to one or more buffers     of audio data
> (multiple buffers are used with non-interleaved PCM data). The
> callback is responsible for not freeing or altering this buffer until
> it is called again.

In the `AudioConverterComplexInputDataProc` callback, When I try to return a ioData with it's `mBuffers[0].mData == NULL`, I got this crash.